# Strange console output from (program):1 in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I'm seeing some strange output in the developer console from a web application:

```
[object Object] (program):1
```

It's as if `Object.prototype.toString()` is being called on something and output to the console however I can find no references to any code writing console.log's.  Does anyone know what that (program):1 means as the source file? clicking it takes me to a new browser tab which is blank.